# php export multiple csv files using a function

Tags: php

I wrote a function in php to write data from database table to csv file:

```
  function export( $result,$filename)
{
    header( 'Content-Type: application/csv' );
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');  
    $output = fopen("php://output", "w");  
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  
    {  
         fputcsv($output, $row);  
    }  
    fclose($output);  
    exit;
}
```

I had to put  `exit;` or `die` at the end to prevent html code from being printed with the csv file , but the problem is when i call this function twice for two different files

```
export($result1,"file1.csv");
export($result2,"file2.csv");
```

it return one file only !

I think the exit is causing the problem ,but how can i resolve this ?

**Update:**

With or without the exit; statement the execution of php page simply stops at the first call of the function why it that ?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The first exit; statement stops the execution of your script.
2. You cannot trigger two downloads through header. You should generate the 2 csv files on disk (without header(...)) and then provide 2 separate links for download. Or tar gz the 2 files and provide the archive download prompt through header.

Comment: With or without  the exit; statement the execution of php page simply stops at the first call of the function why it that ?

Comment: I tried something similar, and the second function executes: https://pastebin.com/ZVXLWq1K
The resulting CSV contains the data passed to the function + the headers already sent error.